# FPDF Sub List with Tag-based formatting

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to generate list using FPDF and Tag-based formatting, the main level list working fine, but the indent of the 2nd level doesn't appear correctly.

My code as below

```
....
$outline = '
<p><strong>Basics to Macros & VBA Code</strong></p>
<li>Create a Macro MsgBox</li>

<lii>test</lii>
<lii>test 1</lii>

<li>Workbook and Worksheet</li>
<li>Object Range</li>
<li>Object Variables</li>
<li>If Then Statement</li>
<li>Loop</li>
<li>Macro Errors</li>
'

// Stylesheet
$pdf->SetStyle("p","Century Gothic","N",12,"0,0,0");
$pdf->SetStyle("li","Century Gothic","N",0,"0,0,0",10,chr(149));
$pdf->SetStyle("lii","Century Gothic","N",0,"0,0,0",20,chr(28));
$pdf->SetStyle("liii","Century Gothic","N",0,"0,0,0",30,chr(254));
$pdf->SetStyle("strong","GOTHICB0","N",14,"102,153,153",0);

......

$pdf->WriteTag(0,5,$outline,0,"L",0,7);

......
```

**Output**

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]